# Creating scree plot before or after varimax rotation

Tags: r, pca, psychology, factor-rotation

I am performing a principal components analysis using the psych package in R. I have the results for a PCA with varimax rotation, but I can only figure out how to make a scree plot for the PCA without rotation (using the scree function on the original data).

Should I be trying to make a scree plot that includes the varimax rotation? Or is it typical to only generate scree plots that do not include a rotation? If this is typical, how do I do this?